# .NET 3.5 WCF request filtering

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

Can anyone say is there any way to configure request filtering for WCF get request on .NET 3.5?
Specifically I want to pass datetime in UTC format as a part of a line like webservicehost/webservicemethod/param1/param2/1-16-2012T11:48:50 and I have got a problem with colons inside time because IIS treats it as a port or smth like directory name where colon is definitely illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing the parameters as [query strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) instead, which will allow you to **enclose the timestamp value in single quotes**. For example:

> http://webservicehost/webservicemethod?param1=&param2=&param3='1-16-2012T11:48:50'

Comment: Yes, I definitely can but the question is about how to perform the configuration of IIS using .net 3.5 (in 4.0 there are several possibilities to do that).